# Scaling UIView after Rotation causes jump in initial scale

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, rotation, cgaffinetransform

I have a view which I would like to scale and rotate with gesture recognisers. I calculate new bounds for scale like so:

```
let newBounds = moveView.bounds.applying(CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: scalee, y: scalee))
```

And it works fine without rotation getting involved. After simple CGAffineTransform rotation for let's say 45 degrees I try to scale once again and the first calculation has too drastic scale for the first time, and works fine after.

It seems like rotation changes the frame, and that somehow has something to do with that scale, not sure how or why..

Here's code to recreate this issue :

```
      DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+2) {
            self.moveView.bounds = self.moveView.bounds.applying(CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 1.1, y: 1.1))
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+3) {
            self.moveView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: 0.7)
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+4) {
            self.moveView.bounds = self.moveView.bounds.applying(CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 1.1, y: 1.1)) 
            // This gets view too big !
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+5) {
            self.moveView.bounds = self.moveView.bounds.applying(CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: 1.1, y: 1.1))
        }
```